# How can I continuously read from a gzipped file while it is being written to?

Tags: java, gzip, inputstream, fileinputstream

Java's GZIPInputStream and Apache's GzipCompressorInputStream both disable themselves as soon as they reach EOF.

I want to be able to decompress a file which is being written to and when there's not enough data available for decompression or there is no data at all to simply get -1 and be able to keep trying to read until data becomes available as with a regular FileInputStream.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/gzip/GzipCompressorInputStream.html

Here's a main method showing the problem.
I'd like to be able to keep reading once more data is available in the file. I compress the strings "a" and "b". I write the gzipped "a" to the file then read it. I then write the gzipped "b" to the file but the same InputStream will never be able to read it because it disabled itself when it reached the end of file after reading the gzipped "a".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream firstByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream firstGzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(firstByteArrayOutputStream);
    firstGzipOutputStream.write("a".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    firstGzipOutputStream.close();
    byte[] firstGzippedBytes = firstByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayOutputStream secondByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream secondGzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(secondByteArrayOutputStream);
    secondGzipOutputStream.write("b".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    secondGzipOutputStream.close();
    byte[] secondGzippedBytes = secondByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    Path combiner = Files.createTempFile("gziptest", "gz");
    FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(combiner.toFile(), false);
    fileWriter.write(firstGzippedBytes);
    fileWriter.close();

    InputStream b = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(combiner.toFile()));

    int fromFile = b.read();
    while (fromFile != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) fromFile);
        fromFile = b.read();
    }

    FileOutputStream fileAppender = new FileOutputStream(combiner.toFile(), true);
    fileAppender.write(secondGzippedBytes);
    fileAppender.close();

    fromFile = b.read();

    while (fromFile != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) fromFile);
        fromFile = b.read();
    }
}
```

I'd rather not have to implement my own inflater...

Contrast that with the following using a simple FileInputStream with no compression. All the data is read - the stream starts returning data once it is written to the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream firstByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    firstByteArrayOutputStream.write("a".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    firstByteArrayOutputStream.close();
    byte[] firstGzippedBytes = firstByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayOutputStream secondByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    secondByteArrayOutputStream.write("b".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    secondByteArrayOutputStream.close();
    byte[] secondGzippedBytes = secondByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    Path combiner = Files.createTempFile("gziptest", "gz");
    FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(combiner.toFile(), false);
    fileWriter.write(firstGzippedBytes);
    fileWriter.close();

    InputStream b = new FileInputStream(combiner.toFile());

    int fromFile = b.read();
    while (fromFile != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) fromFile);
        fromFile = b.read();
    }

    FileOutputStream fileAppender = new FileOutputStream(combiner.toFile(), true);
    fileAppender.write(secondGzippedBytes);
    fileAppender.close();

    fromFile = b.read();

    while (fromFile != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) fromFile);
        fromFile = b.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: You realize you don't need to give the Apache or Java upstream your *real* File object, but can just give them a wrapper or other custom input stream that only reports EOF when you know (however you find out out-of-band) that there's no more content coming in the future?

Comment: I find your phrasing a little condescending. What do you reccomend my intermediate stream does? There's no end-of-file notification. The file stream simply returns -1 for a read when there's no data. Later when there's data it returns it. It's the GZIP input stream which eagerly disable themselves with an end of file flag which they set when they get a -1 at the appropriate time.

Comment: gzip -- as a format -- allows multiple compressed streams to be concatenated together with the same effect as concatenating the plaintext. If a library doesn't support that properly, *it's a buggy implementation* and can be reported upstream as such.

Comment: This bug report might just be another manifestation of the same problem : https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8081450

Comment: Looks very much related, yes. BTW, this bug may prevent impacted implementations from decompressing "rsyncable gzip" archives, which occasionally reset the compression table.